# Why doesn't asarray directly modify my list here?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to change the first element of each scenario here but it doesn't seem to work. I thought asarray modifies the original object instead of making a copy.

> ```
>  input:  
>  x = ([1, 2, 3],[4,5,6])    
>  np.asarray(x)[0][0] = 42    
>  print(x)  
>
>  output:  
>  ([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])  
>
>  input:
>  x = [1,2,3]  
>  np.asarray(x)[0] = 42   
>  print(x)
>
>  output:  
>  [1, 2, 3]
> ```

Comment: How would `asarray` modify the original object? In this case, it returns a *new object*, a `numpy.ndarray`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`asarray` only returns the original object if the original object was already an array. If you pass `asarray` a nested list, it will copy the list's data into a new array. For other types, it may return a view or a copy, depending on whether a view is possible.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the use of asarray then...Can you show me an example where asarray is unique compared to just referencing the element's location and editing or or just using np.array

Comment: @user9028381: `asarray` is usually only used for "read-only" input. Its purpose is to ensure you have an array, without copying if you don't need to copy.

Comment: To be clear - `asarray` is just a shorthand for `array(..., copy=False)`. `copy=False` means _if the input is already an array_, don't make a copy. Your input is not an array, so it makes no difference which function you call.

Comment: @user9028381 `np.asarray` will not make a copy unless necessary. If you pass it a `list` object, a copy is necessary. Python lists are not arrays, unless you want an `object` dtype array, but numpy (very sensibly) assumes that isn't what you want